# ActiveRecord: Initialize an object with ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple method that check for an existing `User` and if not found it will create it and will create also a `Profile` object.

Since the Profile requires the `user_id` to be saved, I need somehow to initialize the User with an ID if it does not exist.

I ended up with something like this, but this is not presetting a `user_id` when initialized the user.

```
 def create_or_update_user(user)
   user_object = User.find_or_initialize_by_external_id(user['external_id'])

   if user_object.new_record?
     user_profile = user_object.build_profile(params)
   end
   user_object.save

 end
```

Any idea how can I set the ID when initialized the User record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can, and even so I dont think you should.  If you assign an `id` to your user without creating a record, theres a chance that `id` may be taken by the time you finally save it.

Whats wrong with saving the user, then building and saving the profile?